# Authenticate Web UI using OAuth2 Access Token from ADFS

Tags: adfs, mobile, oauth, mobile-view

In an Ionic mobile app, we need to access the SharePoint API **and** to show a SharePoint Web UI in an Ionic WebView (essentially a browser inside the app). We're using OnPrem ADFS on Windows Server 2012 and OnPrem SharePoint 2013. Here's what we do:

**1. [Setup OAuth2](http://www.gi-architects.co.uk/2016/04/setup-oauth2-on-adfs-3-0/) and add a Relying Party Trust and a Client in ADFS 3**

http://www.gi-architects.co.uk/2016/04/setup-oauth2-on-adfs-3-0/

**2. From the mobile app, call ADFS to obtain an OAuth Access Token**

First, GETing:

```
https://myadfsdomain/adfs/oauth/authorize
    ?response_type=code
    &client_id=MYCLIENTID
    &redirect_uri=https://myserver/callback
    &resource=MYRelyingPartyId
```

then POSTing the responseCode Eg:

```
$http({method: "post", 
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 
   url: "https://myadfsdomain/adfs/oauth2/token", 
   data: "client_id=MYCLIENTID&code=" + responseCode + "&redirect_uri=https://myserver/callback&grant_type=authorization_code"  })
```

See also http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/03/09/OAUTH2-Authentication-with-ADFS-3.0.html

We now have an OAuth2 Access Token.

**3. Use that token to call the SharePoint API**

```
GET /the-api-method
 Host: example.com
 Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

***Question***

Question is, how can that access token be used to access the SharePoint Web UI? Can it be exchanged for a SharePoint Web UI cookie ([FedAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388696/federated-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-getting-rtfa-and-fedauth-cookies)) so that a WebView placed in the app can show a SharePoint web page to the authenticated user without the user having to login again?

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39103277/2325676), it sounds like OAuth2 for ADFS3 (Windows Server 2012) only works when calling a SharePoint API, NOT when calling a SharePoint Web UI. Is that correct?

As ADFS on Windows Server 2016 [now supports more OAuth2 grant types](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ausoemteam/2016/08/19/whats-new-in-windows-server-2016-standard-edition-part-2-identity/), is this now possible in server 2016? If so, how does the access token get exchanged for a cookie or does it?

Comment: I have the issue, I need to use the token to call the SharePoint REST API, is there a way to send it with the header in ajax call?

Comment: Were you able to configure custom Web API with Share point. I am trying to do the same with SharePoint 2016. Any Clue will a big help for me

Answer (score 0):

You probably already found the answer, but SharePoint 2013 doesn't directly support OAuth authentication.  It does support claims based SAML authentication and can work directly with ADFS with some configuration.  So you might be able to avoid OAuth and just use ADFS.

Here is how to configure SharePoint 2013 to work with ADFS: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235.aspx